# Javascript interval not clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a fairly complex page with lots of ajax calls and subsequent dom manipulation. On one particular call it sets an interval with a time limit(essentially a timer). I have set up `clearInterval()` everywhere and even in the function but in very particular use cases(it is complex and I can't determine the exact cause and steps to reproduce the defect) .

```
$(function() {
  window.timer_interval; 
  // ...
})
function timer()
{
    var current = 0; 
    time_limit = 60;                                
    window.timer_interval = setInterval(function() {
        minute = ( "0" +  Math.round(Math.floor((time_limit - current)/60))).slice(-2); 
        seconds = ("0" + ((time_limit - current)%60)).slice(-2); 

        $('#timer').html(minute + ":" + seconds);

        if (current >= time_limit) {
            clearInterval(window.timer_interval); 
            window.timer_interval = false; 
        }
        current = current + 1; 
    }, 1000);
}
```

I have used firbug to detect the value for `window.timer_interval` , it is `false` and even the condition is satisfied.One thing might be that that a couple of image transfers fail
(this is possible application behaviour with code written to gracefully degrade). I am developing in Mozilla.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you're setting the interval, and then setting the interval again without clearing it first, so that whatever was set previous will run forever.

If I am right adding a check to clear the interval before `setInterval` will correct the problem.  I've created a function to the code below that will take place when you call `setInterval`.

```
// starts an interval function, making sure to cancel one that is previously running
function startSharedInterval(func) {
    if (window.timer_interval) {
        clearInterval(window.intervalID);
        window.timer_interval = 0;
    }

    window.timer_interval = setInterval(func, 1000);
};

// ... in timer() 
startSharedInterval(function () {
    minute = ( "0" +  Math.round(Math.floor((time_limit - current)/60))).slice(-2)  ; 
    // ... rest of code
});
```

If you only have one timer, then you can avoid using global scope and take advantage of using closures so that the timer is always cleared.

In the code below, `interval_id` is created in the parent `timer()` function.  This will be available to the inner anonymous function to clear when its execution after 60 is completed.  You may have multiple instances running simultaneously this way.

```
function timer() {

    var current = 0;
    var time_limit = 60;
    var interval_id = setInterval(function () {

        minute = ("0" + Math.round(Math.floor((time_limit - current) / 60))).slice(-2);
        seconds = ("0" + ((time_limit - current) % 60)).slice(-2);

        $('#timer').html(minute + ":" + seconds);

        if (current >= time_limit) {
            clearInterval(interval_id);
        }
        current = current + 1;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: The problem is , my original function has a clear interval as well , I  am trying to debug with firebug, the condition is satisfied(i.e. current is greater than time_limit) and the clearInterval is being called. The interval is still called infinitely. How is this possible when I am using only one name(windows.timer_interval) for the interval. There are no other intervals on the page.

Comment: One way that it is possible is that if you call `timer()` again before the condition to clear timer is met.  Then the original timer is never cleared.

Comment: To put it simply, any time there's a line in your code starting with `window.timer_interval = setInterval`, put `if(window.timer_interval){ clearInterval(window.timer_interval); }` immediately before it.

Comment: I am not sure how it worked(because I was pretty sure I was clearing it everywhere) but heck it does work now. Accepting answer. I also did unbinding of an error event, that might have been messing with the interval.